# JButton Not performing Any Action

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, actionlistener

Hi I have a `JButton` defined like:

```
private JButton btnExp;

private JPanel jpShow = new JPanel();
jpShow.setLayout(null);

btnExp = new JButton("Export");
btnExp.setBounds(100, 250, 120, 25);

jpShow.add(jspTable);
jpShow.add(btnExp);
//Adding Panel to Window.
getContentPane().add(jpShow);

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    try{
        Object obj = ae.getSource();
        if (obj == btnExp) {
            FileWriter excel = new FileWriter("File.TSV");

            for(int i = 0; i < dtmCustomer.getColumnCount(); i++){
                excel.write(dtmCustomer.getColumnName(i) + "\t");
            }
            excel.write("\n");

            for(int i=0; i< dtmCustomer.getRowCount(); i++) {
                for(int j=0; j < dtmCustomer.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                    excel.write(dtmCustomer.getValueAt(i,j).toString()+"\t");
                }
                excel.write("\n");
            }
            excel.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "File Written","Success", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Am trying to get the `JTable` to be exported after the user clicks the button but nothing happens and no exception is raised. Am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: See also [*How to Use Actions*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not adding the ActionListener to your button correctly. The correct way is:

```
btnExp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // add here the contents in your actionPerformed method
  }
})
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I t is just that I have added other Buttons like that Before and I was Wondering why this should not work the same way. Anyway I will go with your method.

Answer (score 2):

1. The code you post will not even compile
2. You should add the `ActionListener` to your `JButton` as @Dan already showed in his answer
3. You should make sure you close the `FileWriter` in a `finally` block. Now, when an exception occurs it will not be closed
4. You will end up with a non-responsive UI if you export the table on the *Event Dispatch Thread*. Consider using a `SwingWorker`. Consult the [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) tutorial for more information
5. Avoid the use of `setLayout( null )` and `setBounds`. Use a decent `LayoutManager` instead